# When does backup manager save the data in android?

Tags: android

I am using Android `BackupManager` to backup some data. In the Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html#Basics)  it says call the  `dataChanged()` method but will be called in future, though it is never happening. I can only use the bgmr tools and backup or restore does not happen  programmatically. Any reason for this and how long does it generally take?

Answer (score 0):

It will generally backup things in batches, but you cannot control it from your app. You can see the queue with the provided command line tools, if your apps is queued for backup, you shouldn't need to do anything more.

It does work, so it might be a problem with your device or lack of connectivity. Does it work in another device?

Comment: thanks for ur reply... now it does take back up then again i reinstall and then i can see that the value is restored.... however the next day i uninstall the app and then i reinstall to check, the value is not restored??